# Sendgrid Login Error: You are not authorized to access SendGrid, please contact Support

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-templates

[Acount created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nv8Ya.png)

When i create acount in sendgrid i get a message like this one says 'Please provide further information' 'Please contact Support to answer a few more questions.'

So when i try to contact with support to answer their question website want me to login but i  can't because when i try to login get this error [login error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6X6V2.png). If i try to troubleshot logging whit this [troubleshot logging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGD1q.png) website again want me to login. [want me to login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/958Bh.png) How can i?